# Excel Convert text to timestamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following text timestamp in cell A1. `22-OCT-13 03.40.00.000000000 AM`. In B1 I have the following formula: `=TIME(HOUR(MID(A1,11,2)),MIN(MID(A1,14,2)),SECOND(MID(A1,17,2)))`.

It yields 12:40 AM. The hour function returns zero, but the minute function works fine. I can't figure out what's up with it.

Comment: Hey, I just realised that you might be missing the AM/PM at the end. Edited my answer to consider that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MIN` is the 'minimum' formula that returns the smallest value out of a list of values, not the `MINUTE` formula.

I think you are not familiar with `TIME()`, `HOUR()` or `MINUTE()`.

`TIME()` takes 'normal' values and converts them into a time value. If you have `TIME(H, M, S)`, `H` is the number of hours (not a timestamp), `M` is the number of minutes (not a timestamp either) and `S` is the number of seconds (yet again, not a timestamp).

`HOUR()` takes a time value and extracts the hour from it.

`MINUTE()` and `SECOND()` are similar to `HOUR()`. What you probably meant to have is:

```
=TIME(MID(A1,11,2),MID(A1,14,2),MID(A1,17,2))
```

When you use `MID()` you are getting a number, not a timestamp. So, `HOUR` takes that number, interprets it as a timestamp and return the hour. In your example, the first `MID` returns `03`. In excel, if you convert that to a timestamp, you get 03/01/1900 00:00 (in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format) and the hour is thus `0`.

---

EDIT:

By the way, you could use this formula if you want to keep the date and time (not forgetting the AM/PM at the end:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":"),":",".",3)*1
```

The original date/time is almost one that can be understood by Excel. Replace all `.` with `:` and then replace the 3rd (last) `:` by `.` and multiply by 1 to tell Excel to convert that to a number. Just format the result as time and that should do it.